# How to fix the code block widgets GUI error

Tags: user-interface, widget, c++-cli

Could somebody help me it?  Thanks in advance.
When I use codeblock to create an widgets GUI, I encounter this error popup window below:

The window show message below: Because I just register in this websit and could not paste image.
So the image could be found in link:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,18677.0.html

widgets GUI error Filename:CommandLine Error:end of statement expected(; or lf)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? There is no image on the page you link to as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the RC2 and the issue has been fixed.
RC2: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,18673.0.html